# Not getting Integer Overflow

Tags: c, overflow, signed-integer

Say I want to print some values. I am assuming that I should get Integer Overflow if my signed variable exceeds from `TMin` and `TMax` (in this case, using 4 byte int, `0x7FFFFFFF` as `Tmax` and `0x80000000` as `Tmin`) but in these example I am not getting what I expect (explained in comments):

```
// Tmax = 0x7FFFFFFF == 2147483647 
// Tmin = 0x80000000 == -2147483648 
printf("1- overflow test: %d\n", 0x7FFFFFFF+1 ); // overflow - how compiler finds out it's a signed value, not an Unsigned one
printf("2- overflow test: %d\n", 0x80000000-1 ); // in contrast, why I am not getting an integer overflow here
printf("3- overflow test: %d\n", (int) 0x80000000-1 ); // overflow (Expected)
printf("4- overflow test: %d\n",(int) (0x7FFFFFFF+1)); // overflow (Expected)
```

Comment: First one - you're using signed formatting. Second - literal gets calculated at runtime, so no overflow. And signed overflows are undefined, anyway.

Comment: @TNW an expression like `0x7FFFFFFF+1` gets calculated at compile time.

Comment: @TNW so why there is different behavior for # 1 compare to # 2 (since the syntax looks the same to me)

Comment: @HoomanYar why not? Its undefined behavior and that is literally undefined. Anything may happen at that point.

Comment: @HoomanYar  as the answers say: it is undefined behaviour. So it does not have to do anything you might expect, or even be consistent.

Comment: @WeatherVane: And invokes undefined behaviour with 32 bit or smaller `int`.

Comment: `0x80000000-1` is not signed integer overflow as `0x80000000` is likely some unsigned .

Comment: Guys, if I knew the behavior is not predictable I wouldn't send this question. Actually that's my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is not always experiencing signed integer overflow - which is undefined behavior.

The following is unsigned  math as `0x80000000` is likely an unsigned integer.  Hexadecimal constants are of the type that first fits them `int, unsigned, long, unsigned long, ...`

```
printf("2- overflow test: %d\n", 0x80000000-1 );
```

`0x80000000-1` is an unsigned type as `0x80000000` first fits in an unsigned type, likely `unsigned` with the value of `2147483648u`.  `2147483648u - 1` --> `2147483647u`.

`0x7FFFFFFF+1` is a signed type as `0x7FFFFFFF` first fits in a signed type, likely `int` with the value of `INT_MAX`.
`int` + `int` --> `int` *and* `INT_MAX + 1` --> overflow.

---

OP said "0x80000000 as Tmin" is certainly a mis-understanding.  In C, with 32-bit `int/unsigned`, `0x80000000` is a hexadecimal constant with the value of `2147483648`.  For OP, Tmin is more likely `-INT_MAX - 1`.

Comment: Once you invoke UB, all bets are off, no matter if the rest is ok. IOW: UB is virulent.

Comment: @Olaf OP's code comments "why I am not getting an integer overflow here" is certainly discovered from a lack of a compile time warning. The reason is discussed in this answer.  Of course UB is a run-time issue.

Comment: Ok, got your point. My comment was mostly that after the first overflow, all bets are off for the following code.

Comment: @Oalf  I think it is even worse than that.  Some compilers take advantage if in _later_ code, UB will certainly occur, they perform some interesting optimizations on prior code - like not even executing it!  I followed some interesting debates on this issue about the legitimacy of that.  Moral of the story: UB is UB is UB.

Comment: I completely agree with that standpoint. It is full in-line with allowing the compiler to rearrange code internally, as long as the _observable behaviour_ is correct. As you might have notice I don't tend to be very tolerant to failures. (Things are different if a system has to tolerate failures ...:-)

Comment: See @SouravGhosh's answer. While `0x80000000 - 1` is not UB, using `%d` actually. is.

Comment: @Oalf Consider [C11 §6.5.2.2 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139204/not-getting-integer-overflow/35139463?noredirect=1#comment58000288_35139254).  I suspect it will take an SO post to clear that up.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me tell you, (signed) integer overflow invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In that scenario, anything can happen. You can neither trust nor reasonify the output of a code having UB.

Just to clarify, even

```
printf("2- overflow test: %d\n", 0x80000000-1 );
```

is UB. Though `0x80000000-1` is `unsigned` and not an overflow in itself, using `%d` will lead to a type mismatch which will technically lead to UB.

Regarding the Undefined behavior, from `C11`, annex §J.2,

> Conversion to or from an integer type produces a value outside the range that can be
>   represented.

Comment: What about signed `long` `signed `char`? etc.? (Sorry for being nit-picky. Just think more general ;-)

Comment: @Olaf is changing that to "signed integer types" makes it better?

Comment: @Olaf I'm referring to §6.2.5/17. Will that be ok? :)

Comment: Why not just cite (and link) the standard. See 3.4.3 for instance. Whats wrong with just "signed integer"? ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Updated now. Please review once.

Comment: "... lead to a type mismatch which will technically lead to UB." is not so as there is an exception in C - now to find it.  C11 §6.5.2.2 6.  Since the value is representable in both `int` and `unsigned`, no UB.

Comment: @chux Sorry, I did not get your point. `%d` with unsigned >> _"If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined."_ or am I missing something here?

Comment: Read carefully C11 §6.5.2.2 6 "...one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types".  As I read it, it means that is an `int/unsigned` is expected yet a `unsigned/int` is given in a `f(...)` and the value is representable in both types, like `0x7FFFFFFF`, then there is no UB.

Comment: @chux Confused!! Isn't that about the missing prototype? Is that applicable for variadic functions? Just the case before that, the varidic notation is mentioned explicitly. However, let me read through it again, carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to invoke integer overflow is undefined behavior. As per standard, in that case anything, including outwardly appearing non-overflow can happen. What this outputs is uninteresting and irrelevant.

It may be that your compiler optimizes it out. It may be that your system refuses to be used in such a way, it may be that a sack of rice falling in china caused a butterfly effect that lead to this. Its anything but defined what happens there.

It may also be that your system decided that its integers are bigger. Only the lower limit of integer sizes (2 byte) is mandated in c (at least 4 is typical for standard computers). Your system could have 8 byte integers, or even bigger ones.

Comment: so if int overflow happens pretty much randomly, how we can determine if say a random input would get an overflow or not?

Comment: @HoomanYar By ensuring your value goes not above whats permitted in your integer. Overflow only happens when you go above that. So if your int is 32 bit (which it most likely is), just dont do over 2^32 -1 in value or not over 2^32 / 2 - 1 for signed integers, and not below - 2^32 for signed integers

Comment: *"Only the lower limit of integer sizes (4 byte) is mandated in c."* - 2 bytes, surely?

Comment: @HoomanYar: Nothing happens randomly unless you have some source of true white noise in your system. Please carefully think about the meaning of **undefined**, like in _undefined behaviour_. Prepare for nasal daemons, your computer commiting suicide by jumping out of the window, etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane In modern systems for simplicity. But feel free to edit the caveat in.

Comment: @WeatherVane changed it.

Comment: @Magisch: Most systems sold have 16 bit `int`. And the standard allows for padding bits.

Answer (score 1):

C is kind of inconsistent about numeric exceptions.

There are a few things you can do that almost always cause problems.  If you divide by 0, your program will usually crash pretty hard, just as if you'd accessed an invalid pointer.

There are a few things you can do that are guaranteed not to cause a problem.  If you say

```
unsigned int i = UINT_MAX;
```

and then add 1 to it, it's guaranteed to wrap around to 0.

And then there are a number of things where the behavior is undefined or unspecified.  Signed integer overflow is one of these.  Strictly speaking it's undefined (anything can happen, you can't depend on it).  In practice, most computers quietly wrap around, just like for unsigned arithmetic.

Now, everything I've said has been about the run-time behavior of a program, but in this question's posted code fragment, all the arithmetic happens at compile time.  Compile-time arithmetic operates mostly according to the same rules as run-time, but not always.  Modern compilers tend to warn you about problematic compile-time arithmetic (my copy of gcc emits three warnings for the posted fragment), but not always.